# Flutter Text Field Widget Won't Display

Tags: flutter, textfield

I'm new to `Flutter` and trying to learn it from the [codelabs - flutter](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter/#4). The TextField widget won't show up.And I'm stuck here for an hour.

I ended up copying the code methods, still leaves my app empty.

Here's my code:

```
class ChatScreen extends StatefulWidget{
//  @override
//  State createState() => new ChatScreenState();

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return new ChatScreenState();
  }
}

//STATE OF CHAT SCREEN
class ChatScreenState extends State<ChatScreen>{

  //NEW COMPONENT EDIT TEXT INPUT LAYOUT
  final TextEditingController _textController = new TextEditingController();

  //WIDGET METHOD
  Widget _buildTextComposer() {
    return new Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
      child: new TextField(
        controller: _textController,
        onSubmitted: _handleSubmitted,
        decoration: new InputDecoration.collapsed(hintText: "Send a message"),
      ),
    );

  }

  //METHOD FOR CLEARING
  void _handleSubmitted(String text){
    _textController.clear();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: _buildTextComposer(),

    );
  }

}
```

I already included the body: `_buildTextComposer()` from the Scaffold.

Comment: do you have any error ? or it just don't show up

Comment: I didn't see any error. I cannot post all the code and trying to edit because Stackoverflow complain of a lot of code

Comment: you can post a link to the code not all the code use this https://gist.github.com

Comment: I pasted my code in there.

Comment: did you try to restart the app or or just use hot reload ?

Comment: I always do full restart and not hot reload. I'm working on Android Studio as my IDE.

Answer (score 0):

From the codelabs tutorial

[codelabs-flutter #3](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter/#3) , I didn't notice they change something from the `runApp()`

From:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    new MaterialApp(
      title: "Friendlychat",
      home: new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text("Friendlychat"),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

To:

```
void main() {
  runApp(new FriendlychatApp()); //THERE IS NO COMMENT INDICATING THIS IS MODIFIED
}
```

In some page they indicate it. Comments from the right

```
// Modify the ChatScreen class definition to extend StatefulWidget.

class ChatScreen extends StatefulWidget {                     //modified
  @override                                                        //new
  State createState() => new ChatScreenState();                    //new
}
```